# I need to connect visual studio to serial connected microscope camera for feature tracking with opencv? Edit

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, serial-port, robotics

I need to connect visual studio to serial connected microscope camera for feature tracking with opencv but videoCapture(0) and videoCapture(1) doesnt recognize the microscope camera and i can only access this microscope camera from NImax software so what can i do to access it from visual studio c++ with opencv?